# Unsupported format character when using string formatting

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, python-2.x

The problem is that I'm getting this error message:

```
unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 27
```

While using the string formatting on this:

```
v = 60 / 100.0
messenger.append("Base Skill Level +%,0f" % chop(20 + 15 * v))
```

`messenger.append` works just like the `print()` if someone would be curious.

The question is, how to solve this? I cant see the problem here as far as `,` is required here: `%,0f`.

I'm using Python version 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant `%.0f` instead of `,0f`. As far as I know, there is no such thing as ,0f

Comment: Good point! I though that it was `,0f` but nvm ... thank you!